# Необходимо написать функцию на языке Python3 print_fio

Tags: python

Задача:

> Напишите функцию print_fio(name, surname, patronymic), которая
> принимает три параметра: name – имя человека; surname – фамилия
> человека; patronymic – отчество человека; а затем выводит на печать
> ФИО человека (на одной строке, только первые буквы в порядке
> surname-name-patronymic).
>
> Необходимые и дополнительные условия: Для считывания текста
> используйте команду input(); для печати текста на экране используйте
> команду print(), добавив параметр sep='' для печати на одной строке.
> Используйте def для объявления функции.

Решение:

```
a = input("Введите имя ")
b = input("Введите отчество ")
c = input("Введите фамилию ")
first_name = a
patronymic = b
last_name = c 
def print_fio(first_name, last_name, patronymic):
   print(f"{first_name[0].upper()}+{patronymic[0].upper()}+{last_name[0].upper()}")
```

Вывод:

```
Введите имя Иван
Введите отчество Сидоров
Введите фамилию Петрович
```

И далее ничего не печатает.

Однако, в рамках условия в решении должны содержаться первая заглавная буква ФИО.
Подскажите, в каком месте я ошибся в коде ?

Comment: `И далее ничего не печатает.` а вы функцию не вызывали, т.е. нет `print_fio(first_name, last_name, patronymic)`

Comment: и зачем вам `a b c` тут. Да и `+` в `f-строке` не нужны

Comment: да и с порядком надо разобраться. Как вывода, так и параметров в функции.

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли объявить саму функцию, также конкатенацию через + здесь делать не нужно для строчного вывода текста.
Повторно заключать в переменную введённый текст не нужно, Вы уже создаёте переменные с введённым текстом.

```
a = input("Введите имя ")
b = input("Введите фамилию ")
c = input("Введите отчество ")

def print_fio(a, b, c):
   print(f"{b[0].upper()}{a[0].upper()}{c[0].upper()}")

print_fio(a, b, c)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Благодарю за коммент!